# Core 2 Razor Pages OnGetAsync Load Static File

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way with Razor pages code behind to load a static file as I can do with a traditional MVC controller? I've been playing around with this for a few hours this morning and can't seem to find a way to accomplish this. Any input is appreciated!

Razor Page Code Behind:

```
    public async void OnGetAsync()
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Request;
        var sessionId = request.Query.FirstOrDefault().Value;
        var session = await _httpService.ValidateSession(sessionId);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(session?.UserId))
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.UserId, session.UserId),
                new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.BuId, session.BuId),
                new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.SecurityLevel, session.SecurityLevel)
            };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "TNReadyEVP");
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal,
                new AuthenticationProperties { ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), IsPersistent = true, AllowRefresh = false });

            var isAuthenticated = principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

            Redirect("~/wwwroot/index.html");## Heading ##
        }
        else
        {
            RedirectToPage("./Error");
        }
```

MVC Controller

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn()
    {
        var sessionId = HttpContext.Request.Query.FirstOrDefault().Value;
        var session = await _httpService.ValidateSession(sessionId);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(session?.UserId))
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.UserId, session.UserId),
                new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.BuId, session.BuId),
                new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.SecurityLevel, session.SecurityLevel)
            };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "TNReadyEVP");
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, 
                new AuthenticationProperties { ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), IsPersistent = true, AllowRefresh = false });

            var isAuthenticated = principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }
        else
        {
            return Forbid();
        }

        return View("~/wwwroot/index.html");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First I'd like to say that Core 2 is absolutely terrible at reporting errors. Sometimes it does, sometimes code will fail with no Exception report. Aside from that Core 2 is great.

Here's the answer, you'll see I changed the method signature to return IActionResult which enables the use of RedirectToPage and File.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Request;
        var sessionId = request.Query.FirstOrDefault().Value;
        var session = await _httpService.ValidateSession(sessionId);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId))
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.UserId, session.UserId),
                new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.BuId, session.BuId),
                new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.SecurityLevel, session.SecurityLevel)
            };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "TNReadyEVP");
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal,
                new AuthenticationProperties { ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), IsPersistent = true, AllowRefresh = false });

            var isAuthenticated = principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

            return File("index.html", "text/html");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToPage("Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Core 2 is absolutely terrible at reporting errors. Sometimes it does, sometimes code will fail with no Exception report." - do you mean that it is buggy or it just behaves differently from previous .Net version and you need to do more to actually capture all errors? Can you link to more detailed information on this? I've been considering .Net Core 2 for the next project but this may give me a pause.

Comment: I find it to be buggy. Here's a prime example. Setup a default route with a actionName that has a typo. Core will simply render a blank page instead of pushing an error to the console window. Other weird behavior that I discovered as a newbie was that if I set the appropriate code in Startup class to serve static files, the default MVC routes will not work. However I'm glad I stuck with it and have learned a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the root of the problem is:

```
public async void OnGetAsync()
```

You are dispatching an asynchronous operation that is not being awaited, and the context will be disposed - see [cannot access a disposed object asp net identitycore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477799/cannot-access-a-disposed-object-asp-net-identity-core) and [aspnet Mvc issues 7011](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7011)

FIX: Always use

```
 public async Task OnGetAsync()
```

I echo above thoughts about need to report errors rather than sticking your head in the sand. In this case the failure of ASP.NET Core 2.2 to report the error means that you'll have lots of weird problems until you change the method signature.