# Cannot access a disposed object Asp.net Identity Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am getting this error

```
System.ObjectDisposedException
  HResult=0x80131622
  Message=Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.AsyncDisposer.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery>d__21`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.<FindByNameAsync>d__78.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserValidator`1.<ValidateUserName>d__6.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserValidator`1.<ValidateAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.<ValidateUserAsync>d__172.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.<CreateAsync>d__74.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.<CreateAsync>d__79.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at EmployeeController.<Create>d__3.MoveNext() in Controllers\EmployeeController.cs:line 31
```

For the following code

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<Employee> userManager;
    public EmployeeController(UserManager<Employee> userManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    public ActionResult<string> Get()
    {
        return "Test Employee";
    }

    [HttpPost("Create")]
    public async void Create([FromBody]string employee)
    {
        var user = new Employee { UserName = "test@gmail.com", Email = "test@gmail.com" };
        var d = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "1234567");
    }
}
```

*Startup.cs*

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
         options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<Employee, IdentityRole>(opts =>
       {
           opts.Password.RequireDigit = false;
           opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
           opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
           opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
           opts.Password.RequiredLength = 7;
           opts.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

       }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(opts =>
        {
            opts.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opts.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opts.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            cfg.SaveToken = true;
            cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                // standard configuration
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Auth:Jwt:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Auth:Jwt:Audience"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Auth:Jwt:Key"])),
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,

                // security switches
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateAudience = true
            };
        });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Do I need to register something into my DI? I was under the impression that `AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()` would be enough.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are an `async void` victim:

```
[HttpPost("Create")]
public async void Create([FromBody]string employee)
{
    var user = new Employee { UserName = "test@gmail.com", Email = "test@gmail.com" };
    var d = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "1234567");
}
```

You are dispatching an asynchronous operation that is **not** being awaited, and the context will be disposed before the `await context.SaveChangesAsync()` in `CreateAsync`.

Fast, obvious solution:

```
[HttpPost("Create")]
public async Task Create([FromBody]string employee)
{
    var user = new Employee { UserName = "test@gmail.com", Email = "test@gmail.com" };
    var d = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "1234567");
}
```

However, you should always return `IActionResult` from an Action. That makes it easier to change the response code as well as show your intent:

```
[HttpPost("Create")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody]string employee)
{
    var user = new Employee { UserName = "test@gmail.com", Email = "test@gmail.com" };
    var d = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "1234567");

    if (d == IdentityResult.Success)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    else 
    {
        return BadRequest(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, did not know my quick mockup of the method to test and by using void would cause such problems with async. So Task is the equivalent of void in async?

Comment: @chobo2 Yes, exactly. `async void` is perfectly legal, but very dangerous.

Comment: Cool, Just one other question. I see you return the object back in a badrequest that wold have "succeeded:false", is a point to check that or just check the 400 status code?

Comment: @chobo2 That was just an example, probably far from the best. It was just to point that you could return some data to the client along with the 400

Comment: Ah, got you, thought I think what your sending back is not too bad, it has all the errors in json format.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, I forgot add 2 row in my StartUp.cs:

services.AddScoped<UserManager, UserManager>();
services.AddScoped<RoleManager, RoleManager>();

Add it, it will work normally!