# Asp.net Core + Hangfire ends up with closed or disposed connection

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, hangfire

I am using latest Hangfire v1.6 with an asp.net core 2.1 site.  I am using Entity Framework core 2.1

I submit a job to hangfire but I am ending up with errors like my connection is closed or has been disposed.

The exception when ...

> 2018-10-25
>   21:35:29.1990|[]|10100|ERROR|Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query|An
>   exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a
>   query for context type
>   'OmniService.DataAccess.Models.OmniServiceDbContext'.
>   System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. A
>   common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved
>   from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same
>   context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you
>   are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a
>   using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let
>   the dependency injection container take care of disposing context
>   instances. Object name: 'AsyncDisposer'....

I am using Microsoft DI (not autofac) and it seems the only way that I can keep my connection open is to set it up as a Singleton.  Once I do this I see errors that context is tracking an instance that already exists...of course i can ensure that no tracking is used however this seems like it not the solution.

i.e.

> The instance of entity type 'PostedData' cannot be tracked because
>   another instance with the same key value for {'SubmitId'} is already
>   being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one
>   entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using
>   'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
>   conflicting key values.

In terms of setting up dbcontext

```
//hangfire
services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(connectionString));
services.AddDbContext<OmniServiceDbContext>(options => 
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString").Value), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

services.AddTransient(typeof(IPostedDataService), typeof(PostedDataService));
services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
```

So, what I am missing is why does hangfire not like my transient services with respect to dbcontext?

Answer (score 3):

Found my answer with the help of the post below.
I had thought I had missed some Hangfire configuration.  In fact I made this change

OLD

```
public async void ProcessPostedData(Guid submitId, int retry = 0)
```

WORKING

```
public async Task ProcessPostedData(Guid submitId, int retry = 0)
```

I was calling an async method returning void when it should have been Task. I hope this helps someone else save 3 hours.

[Cannot access a disposed object Asp.net Identity Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477799/cannot-access-a-disposed-object-asp-net-identity-core)